# OpenCV - IPP, TBB and CUDA in Python bindings

Tags: python, opencv, compilation, cuda, tbb

I'm using the Python bindings for OpenCV, which is basically done just by compiling the OpenCV package and placing a .pyd file in my Python distribution.

My question is: If I compile the OpenCV package with Intel IPP, TBB and CUDA
, will it affect the Python bindings? And if yes, could I just get the .pyd file from someone who did the compilation (since I'm having some troubles doing this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV-Python is just a wrapper around underlying C++ code. So if you compile with IPP,TBB, your python code also should make use of it.

But regarding CUDA, OpenCV has separate functions for GPU operations. And those functions don't have Python bindings until now. So you won't be able to access them from Python. ( of course, they are planning to create wrapper for GPU functions also, so in future, you can use it, but not now).

Now if you have made all possible optimizations and still thinks code is slow, you will have to use other methods like cython, or write your codes on C and call it from C etc.

Comment: Hello! I would like to send you an email regarding a freelance opportunity. Drop me a message on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/karlphillip) or [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/in/karlphillip) if you are interested.

Comment: Well, I don't use both the accounts, I mailed you in gmail, please check.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125084/accessing-opencv-cuda-functions-from-python-no-pycuda/52436378#answer-52436378