# OpenCV 3.2 CUDA support python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I've just installed OpenCV 3.2 compiling with CUDA support following instruction in http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/11/compiling-opencv-with-cuda-support/ 
I just wonder how to check whether my OpenCV is using CUDA and GPU support when running (I use python2.7)

Answer (score 16):

As you can see in the [link you gave](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/11/compiling-opencv-with-cuda-support/), you can always check whether you have installed `CUDA` correctly by typing this on `python` console.

```
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

If you have CUDA support, you will be seen that `Use CUDA: YES (version)` in the printed text.

<strike>Then you can use [opencv cuda](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d1a/namespacecv_1_1cuda.html) commands in `cv2.cuda` module.</strike>

But as said in that tutorial `CUDA` support is not there at present in python. (As these tutorials are on `OpenCV python` you will get confused whether this will add `CUDA` support for `python`. But it will ***not..***)

> Furthermore, in a GPU-enabled CUDA environment, there are a number of compile-time optimizations we can make to OpenCV, allowing it to take advantage of the GPU for faster computation (but mainly for C++ applications, not so much for Python, at least at the present time).

But as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50968741/2924323), you can get `OpenCL` support on python. As in [this](https://opencv.org/platforms/opencl.html) document,

> Open Computing Language (OpenCL) is an open standard for writing code that runs across heterogeneous platforms including CPUs, GPUs, DSPs and etc.

Edit 1:

Another thing that you can do is, you can write `python` wrappers for each `GPU` methods in `OpenCV C++` and call those methods via `python`. I will not recommend that because this will always copy images and other data between `GPU` memory and `RAM` resulting bad performance. Sometimes this will take more time than `CPU` alone.

Another thing that you can do is writing the whole function you need to do using `GPU` in `C++` and write a `python` wrapper for that function. This is much more better than the previous method but you will need to know `C++`.

There can be even better ways of doing this..

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125084/accessing-opencv-cuda-functions-from-python-no-pycuda/52436378#answer-52436378