# How to train haar cascade on gpu

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencl, gpu

I am trying to train a cascade using opencv's opencv_traincascade method. But the program is very slow as it run on the CPU. Is there any way I can the program on a GPU for faster training. I tried following this link

https://www.cerebrumedge.com/single-post/2017/12/26/Compiling-OpenCV-with-CUDA-and-FFMpeg-on-Ubuntu-1604, but later realized that it does not work for python, atleast according to this link
[OpenCV 3.2 CUDA support python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315483/opencv-3-2-cuda-support-python).
But the person has also mentioned that one can use opencl with python.

Is there anyway I can use opencl to train the cascade on a GPU?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use GPU computing, but I used parallel computing on the CPU and the speed was increased by 4 times.

[image: cpu status]