# Using Opencv Cuda functions from python

Tags: c++, opencv, cython

For one of my course projects, I need to use the OpenCVs GPU libraries. I am working on an existing code where OpenCV python is used and my work is to find a way to access the OpenCV Cuda libraries as right now there are no accessible Python bindings to OpenCV's various CUDA modules.

Two of the functions that i extremely need right now are `cuda::warpPerspective` and `cv::cuda::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch()`.

i tried to implement the `warpPerspective` by following what @ostrumvulpes suggested in [Accessing OpenCV CUDA Functions from Python (No PyCUDA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125084/accessing-opencv-cuda-functions-from-python-no-pycuda) and it is working perfectly. Right now i am stuck in `DescriptorMatcher::knnMatch()`. To be more precise, i need to use the brute-force descriptor matchers `knnmatch` function (CUDA). i searched online for example written in C++, so that i get an initial idea how to convert it via cython to make it work.

Most of the examples that i found is like following:

```
Ptr<cuda::DescriptorMatcher> matcher = 
cuda::DescriptorMatcher::createBFMatcher();
vector< vector< DMatch> > matches;
matcher->knnMatch(descriptors_object_Gpu, descriptors_scene_Gpu, matches, 2);
```

To implement these three lines i first added what i thought was necessary in the .pxd file. My pxd file looks like the following:

**GpuWrapper.pxd**

```
from libcpp cimport bool
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

# References PyObject to OpenCV object conversion code borrowed from OpenCV's own conversion file, cv2.cpp
cdef extern from 'pyopencv_converter.cpp':
    #mrc689 April 20,2017
    void import_array()
    cdef PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat& m)
    cdef bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* o, Mat& m)

cdef extern from 'opencv2/imgproc.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef enum InterpolationFlags:
        INTER_NEAREST = 0
    cdef enum ColorConversionCodes:
        COLOR_BGR2GRAY

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/core.hpp':
    cdef int CV_8UC1
    cdef int CV_32FC1

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef cppclass Size_[T]:
        Size_() except +
        Size_(T width, T height) except +
        T width
        T height
    ctypedef Size_[int] Size2i
    ctypedef Size2i Size
    cdef cppclass Scalar[T]:
        Scalar() except +
        Scalar(T v0) except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef cppclass Mat:
        Mat() except +
        void create(int, int, int) except +
        void* data
        int rows
        int cols

    #added to test the Algorithm class inside core.hpp on May5th 12.52 AM.
    cdef cppclass Algorithm:
        Algorithm() except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/base.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef enum NormTypes:
        NORM_INF= 1,
        NORM_L1= 2,
        NORM_L2= 4,
        NORM_HAMMING= 6,
        NORM_HAMMING2= 7,

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/cuda.hpp' namespace 'cv::cuda':
    cdef cppclass GpuMat:
        GpuMat() except +
        void upload(Mat arr) except +
        void download(Mat dst) const
    cdef cppclass Stream:
        Stream() except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/types.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef cppclass DMatch:
        DMatch() except +
        float distance
        int imgIdx
        int queryIdx
        int trainIdx

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef cppclass Ptr[T]:
        T element_type
        Ptr() except +   


cdef extern from 'opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp' namespace 'cv::cuda':
    cdef cppclass DescriptorMatcher:
        @staticmethod
        Ptr[DescriptorMatcher] createBFMatcher(int normType) except+
        #Expected to see error here
        void knnMatch(GpuMat queryDescriptors, GpuMat trainDescriptors, vector[vector[DMatch]] &matches,int k)

cdef extern from 'opencv2/cudawarping.hpp' namespace 'cv::cuda':
    cdef void warpPerspective(GpuMat src, GpuMat dst, Mat M, Size dsize, int flags, int borderMode, Scalar borderValue, Stream& stream)
    # Function using default values
    cdef void warpPerspective(GpuMat src, GpuMat dst, Mat M, Size dsize, int flags)
```

and my pyx looks like this:

**GpuWrapper.pyx**

```
import numpy as np  # Import Python functions, attributes, submodules of numpy
cimport numpy as np  # Import numpy C/C++ API

def match_feature(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=3] _src,
                               np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] _M):

    np.import_array()
    # Create GPU/device InputArray for src
    cdef Mat src_mat
    cdef GpuMat src_gpu
    pyopencv_to(<PyObject*> _src, src_mat)
    src_gpu.upload(src_mat)

    cdef Mat src_mat_2
    cdef GpuMat src_gpu_2
    pyopencv_to(<PyObject*> _M, src_mat_2) 
    src_gpu_2.upload(src_mat_2) 

    cdef Ptr[DescriptorMatcher] matcher= Ptr() 
    matcher = DescriptorMatcher.createBFMatcher(4)
    cdef vector[vector[DMatch]] matches
    matcher.knnMatch(src_gpu,src_gpu_2,matches,2)
    print("no problem so far")
```

When i tried to compile it i got an error which says `'Ptr[DescriptorMatcher]' has no attribute 'knnMatch'`.

Now as far i understood, the Ptr is a shared pointer of type `DescriptorMatcher`, So there must be something wrong in my way of defining Ptr from .pxd file.

i just dont know how to fix it. I will really appreciate if  someone can help me solving it.

Comment: Have you been able to make it work. What version python and opencv are you using?

Comment: Did you upload your code somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using `Ptr` correctly (it needs dereferencing in Cython before you can get to `knnMatch`).

A good place to look at how to make `Ptr` is the C++ standard library wrappers built into Cython [which wrap the similar classes `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/memory.pxd).

You don't want to do the line `T element_type` since this isn't interpreted as a typedef (like in the OpenCV headers) - it's interpreted as having a member called `element_type` of type `T` (which doesn't exist).

You possibly want to set up some of the other constructors for `Ptr`. As it stands you've only wrapped the default empty one. (It doesn't look like it matters for your code since you get it from a factory function).

Most importantly, you also want to set up the dereference operator (`operator*`). That's probably all you need to implement for it to work:

```
cdef cppclass Ptr[T]:
    Ptr() except + 
    Ptr(Ptr*) except +
    T& operator* () # probably no exceptions
```

To use it you [use the `cython.operator.dereference`](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#c-operators-not-compatible-with-python-syntax):

```
# at the top
from cython.operator cimport dereference

# later
dereference(matcher).knnMatch(src_gpu,src_gpu_2,matches,2)
```

---

(I haven't looked at the rest of the code in detail so I have no comment on whether it is right)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to successfully compile it without any error. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MohammedRashidChowdhury I'm trying to get this to work, but I get a compile error on the Ptr. Any ideas?

GpuWrapper.pyx:77:44: Cannot assign type 'Ptr[T]' to 'Ptr[DescriptorMatcher]'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setupGpuWrapper.py", line 35, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1039, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1161, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)

Comment: @ThijsW You're almost certainly missing a template indicator somewhere (i.e. you're doing something like `cdef Ptr[T] something` or `cdef Ptr something`, when you should have `cdef Ptr[DescriptiorMatcher] something`). It may be a function return value instead. If that isn't enough to help I suggest asking your own question, since it's very hard to tell without code.