# Converting a vector of vectors to numpy array in cython

Tags: c++, opencv, cython

i am trying to access opencvs cuda libraries from python. i am using cython for extension and i followed the answer of @DavidW from [Using Opencv Cuda functions from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828944/using-opencv-cuda-functions-from-python#comment74711428_43829093) to implement one of the functions that i needed.

For example, i need to convert the following three lines in cython.

```
Ptr< cuda::DescriptorMatcher > matcher = cuda::DescriptorMatcher::createBFMatcher();
vector< vector< DMatch> > matches;
matcher->knnMatch(descriptors_object_Gpu, descriptors_scene_Gpu, matches, 2);
```

based on the answer of @DavidW from [Using Opencv Cuda functions from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828944/using-opencv-cuda-functions-from-python#comment74711428_43829093) i implemented the above lines now all i need to do is to send back the variable “matches” (which is a vector of vector Dmatch) to the python.

Now this is where i am stuck. 
So, from my understanding, when the data is passed from python it needs to be converted to opencv objects and after finishing the computation, the same thing(other way around) is needed to send the result back to python.

for converting the objects i followed what @ostrumvulpes did in pyopencv_converter.cpp ([Accessing OpenCV CUDA Functions from Python (No PyCUDA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125084/accessing-opencv-cuda-functions-from-python-no-pycuda).)

The pyopencv_converter.cpp is given below.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "numpy/ndarrayobject.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

static PyObject* opencv_error = 0;

// === FAIL MESSAGE ====================================================================================================

static int failmsg(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char str[1000];

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, str);
    return 0;
}

struct ArgInfo
{
    const char * name;
    bool outputarg;
    // more fields may be added if necessary

    ArgInfo(const char * name_, bool outputarg_)
        : name(name_)
        , outputarg(outputarg_) {}

    // to match with older pyopencv_to function signature
    operator const char *() const { return name; }
};

// === THREADING =======================================================================================================

class PyAllowThreads
{
public:
    PyAllowThreads() : _state(PyEval_SaveThread()) {}
    ~PyAllowThreads()
    {
        PyEval_RestoreThread(_state);
    }
private:
    PyThreadState* _state;
};

class PyEnsureGIL
{
public:
    PyEnsureGIL() : _state(PyGILState_Ensure()) {}
    ~PyEnsureGIL()
    {
        PyGILState_Release(_state);
    }
private:
    PyGILState_STATE _state;
};

// === ERROR HANDLING ==================================================================================================

#define ERRWRAP2(expr) \
try \
{ \
    PyAllowThreads allowThreads; \
    expr; \
} \
catch (const cv::Exception &e) \
{ \
    PyErr_SetString(opencv_error, e.what()); \
    return 0; \
}

// === USING NAMESPACE CV ==============================================================================================

using namespace cv;

// === NUMPY ALLOCATOR =================================================================================================

class NumpyAllocator : public MatAllocator
{
public:
    NumpyAllocator() { stdAllocator = Mat::getStdAllocator(); }
    ~NumpyAllocator() {}

    UMatData* allocate(PyObject* o, int dims, const int* sizes, int type, size_t* step) const
    {
        UMatData* u = new UMatData(this);
        u->data = u->origdata = (uchar*)PyArray_DATA((PyArrayObject*) o);
        npy_intp* _strides = PyArray_STRIDES((PyArrayObject*) o);
        for( int i = 0; i < dims - 1; i++ )
            step[i] = (size_t)_strides[i];
        step[dims-1] = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type);
        u->size = sizes[0]*step[0];
        u->userdata = o;
        return u;
    }

    UMatData* allocate(int dims0, const int* sizes, int type, void* data, size_t* step, int flags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const
    {
        if( data != 0 )
        {
            CV_Error(Error::StsAssert, "The data should normally be NULL!");
            // probably this is safe to do in such extreme case
            return stdAllocator->allocate(dims0, sizes, type, data, step, flags, usageFlags);
        }
        PyEnsureGIL gil;

        int depth = CV_MAT_DEPTH(type);
        int cn = CV_MAT_CN(type);
        const int f = (int)(sizeof(size_t)/8);
        int typenum = depth == CV_8U ? NPY_UBYTE : depth == CV_8S ? NPY_BYTE :
                      depth == CV_16U ? NPY_USHORT : depth == CV_16S ? NPY_SHORT :
                      depth == CV_32S ? NPY_INT : depth == CV_32F ? NPY_FLOAT :
                      depth == CV_64F ? NPY_DOUBLE : f*NPY_ULONGLONG + (f^1)*NPY_UINT;
        int i, dims = dims0;
        cv::AutoBuffer<npy_intp> _sizes(dims + 1);
        for( i = 0; i < dims; i++ )
            _sizes[i] = sizes[i];
        if( cn > 1 )
            _sizes[dims++] = cn;
        PyObject* o = PyArray_SimpleNew(dims, _sizes, typenum);
        if(!o)
            CV_Error_(Error::StsError, ("The numpy array of typenum=%d, ndims=%d can not be created", typenum, dims));
        return allocate(o, dims0, sizes, type, step);
    }

    bool allocate(UMatData* u, int accessFlags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const
    {
        return stdAllocator->allocate(u, accessFlags, usageFlags);
    }

    void deallocate(UMatData* u) const
    {
        if(!u)
            return;
        PyEnsureGIL gil;
        CV_Assert(u->urefcount >= 0);
        CV_Assert(u->refcount >= 0);
        if(u->refcount == 0)
        {
            PyObject* o = (PyObject*)u->userdata;
            Py_XDECREF(o);
            delete u;
        }
    }

    const MatAllocator* stdAllocator;
};

// === ALLOCATOR INITIALIZATION ========================================================================================

NumpyAllocator g_numpyAllocator;

// === CONVERTOR FUNCTIONS =============================================================================================

template<typename T> static
bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* obj, T& p, const char* name = "<unknown>");

template<typename T> static
PyObject* pyopencv_from(const T& src);

enum { ARG_NONE = 0, ARG_MAT = 1, ARG_SCALAR = 2 };

// special case, when the convertor needs full ArgInfo structure
static bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* o, Mat& m, const ArgInfo info)
{
    bool allowND = true;
    if(!o || o == Py_None)
    {
        if( !m.data )
            m.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;
        return true;
    }

    if( PyInt_Check(o) )
    {
        double v[] = {static_cast<double>(PyInt_AsLong((PyObject*)o)), 0., 0., 0.};
        m = Mat(4, 1, CV_64F, v).clone();
        return true;
    }
    if( PyFloat_Check(o) )
    {
        double v[] = {PyFloat_AsDouble((PyObject*)o), 0., 0., 0.};
        m = Mat(4, 1, CV_64F, v).clone();
        return true;
    }
    if( PyTuple_Check(o) )
    {
        int i, sz = (int)PyTuple_Size((PyObject*)o);
        m = Mat(sz, 1, CV_64F);
        for( i = 0; i < sz; i++ )
        {
            PyObject* oi = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(o, i);
            if( PyInt_Check(oi) )
                m.at<double>(i) = (double)PyInt_AsLong(oi);
            else if( PyFloat_Check(oi) )
                m.at<double>(i) = (double)PyFloat_AsDouble(oi);
            else
            {
                failmsg("%s is not a numerical tuple", info.name);
                m.release();
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    if( !PyArray_Check(o) )
    {
        failmsg("%s is not a numpy array, neither a scalar", info.name);
        return false;
    }

    PyArrayObject* oarr = (PyArrayObject*) o;

    bool needcopy = false, needcast = false;
    int typenum = PyArray_TYPE(oarr), new_typenum = typenum;
    int type = typenum == NPY_UBYTE ? CV_8U :
               typenum == NPY_BYTE ? CV_8S :
               typenum == NPY_USHORT ? CV_16U :
               typenum == NPY_SHORT ? CV_16S :
               typenum == NPY_INT ? CV_32S :
               typenum == NPY_INT32 ? CV_32S :
               typenum == NPY_FLOAT ? CV_32F :
               typenum == NPY_DOUBLE ? CV_64F : -1;

    if( type < 0 )
    {
        if( typenum == NPY_INT64 || typenum == NPY_UINT64 || typenum == NPY_LONG )
        {
            needcopy = needcast = true;
            new_typenum = NPY_INT;
            type = CV_32S;
        }
        else
        {
            failmsg("%s data type = %d is not supported", info.name, typenum);
            return false;
        }
    }

#ifndef CV_MAX_DIM
    const int CV_MAX_DIM = 32;
#endif

    int ndims = PyArray_NDIM(oarr);
    if(ndims >= CV_MAX_DIM)
    {
        failmsg("%s dimensionality (=%d) is too high", info.name, ndims);
        return false;
    }

    int size[CV_MAX_DIM+1];
    size_t step[CV_MAX_DIM+1];
    size_t elemsize = CV_ELEM_SIZE1(type);
    const npy_intp* _sizes = PyArray_DIMS(oarr);
    const npy_intp* _strides = PyArray_STRIDES(oarr);
    bool ismultichannel = ndims == 3 && _sizes[2] <= CV_CN_MAX;

    for( int i = ndims-1; i >= 0 && !needcopy; i-- )
    {
        // these checks handle cases of
        //  a) multi-dimensional (ndims > 2) arrays, as well as simpler 1- and 2-dimensional cases
        //  b) transposed arrays, where _strides[] elements go in non-descending order
        //  c) flipped arrays, where some of _strides[] elements are negative
        // the _sizes[i] > 1 is needed to avoid spurious copies when NPY_RELAXED_STRIDES is set
        if( (i == ndims-1 && _sizes[i] > 1 && (size_t)_strides[i] != elemsize) ||
            (i < ndims-1 && _sizes[i] > 1 && _strides[i] < _strides[i+1]) )
            needcopy = true;
    }

    if( ismultichannel && _strides[1] != (npy_intp)elemsize*_sizes[2] )
        needcopy = true;

    if (needcopy)
    {
        if (info.outputarg)
        {
            failmsg("Layout of the output array %s is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)", info.name);
            return false;
        }

        if( needcast ) {
            o = PyArray_Cast(oarr, new_typenum);
            oarr = (PyArrayObject*) o;
        }
        else {
            oarr = PyArray_GETCONTIGUOUS(oarr);
            o = (PyObject*) oarr;
        }

        _strides = PyArray_STRIDES(oarr);
    }

    // Normalize strides in case NPY_RELAXED_STRIDES is set
    size_t default_step = elemsize;
    for ( int i = ndims - 1; i >= 0; --i )
    {
        size[i] = (int)_sizes[i];
        if ( size[i] > 1 )
        {
            step[i] = (size_t)_strides[i];
            default_step = step[i] * size[i];
        }
        else
        {
            step[i] = default_step;
            default_step *= size[i];
        }
    }

    // handle degenerate case
    if( ndims == 0) {
        size[ndims] = 1;
        step[ndims] = elemsize;
        ndims++;
    }

    if( ismultichannel )
    {
        ndims--;
        type |= CV_MAKETYPE(0, size[2]);
    }

    if( ndims > 2 && !allowND )
    {
        failmsg("%s has more than 2 dimensions", info.name);
        return false;
    }

    m = Mat(ndims, size, type, PyArray_DATA(oarr), step);
    m.u = g_numpyAllocator.allocate(o, ndims, size, type, step);
    m.addref();

    if( !needcopy )
    {
        Py_INCREF(o);
    }
    m.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;

    return true;
}

template<>
bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* o, Mat& m, const char* name)
{
    return pyopencv_to(o, m, ArgInfo(name, 0));
}

template<>
PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat& m)
{
    if( !m.data )
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    Mat temp, *p = (Mat*)&m;
    if(!p->u || p->allocator != &g_numpyAllocator)
    {
        temp.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;
        ERRWRAP2(m.copyTo(temp));
        p = &temp;
    }
    PyObject* o = (PyObject*)p->u->userdata;
    Py_INCREF(o);
    return o;
}
```

now in the pyopencv_converter.cpp i saw only conversion of Mat was done. what do i need to do if i want to covert the vector of vector to numpy array and send it back to the python.

i looked at the source code of Opencv object conversion from OpenCV's modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp

i guess i need to use the following portion from the cv2.hpp.

```
template<typename _Tp> static inline PyObject* pyopencv_from_generic_vec(const std::vector<_Tp>& value)
{
    int i, n = (int)value.size();
    PyObject* seq = PyList_New(n);
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        PyObject* item = pyopencv_from(value[i]);
        if(!item)
            break;
        PyList_SET_ITEM(seq, i, item);
    }
    if( i < n )
    {
        Py_DECREF(seq);
        return 0;
    }
    return seq;
}

template<> struct pyopencvVecConverter<DMatch>
{
    static PyObject* from(const std::vector<DMatch>& value)
    {
        return pyopencv_from_generic_vec(value);
    }
};
```

As, i am new to cython i dont know how to implement the above code in my .pxd file.
is it the right way to convert the vector of vectors to numpy? if no then what is the right approach?

I will really appreciate if someone can help me solving it.

Comment: This looks a bit of a nightmare. Your biggest problem is that `DMatch` is a C++ class (based on the code in your previous question) so you can't easily put it in a numpy array. A couple of questions: 1) do you have know for certain that all the `vector<DMatch>`s inside the outer vector are the same length? 2) What do you want to do with the result (i.e. use it in Cython, use it in Python, feed it to existing Python functions)?

Comment: @DavidW, Thank You, for pointing that out, I actually don't need to convert the whole DMatch. i just needed to compute something based on the distance of two DMatch objects. Everything is working now. Though my assumption was wrong, using the GPUs for computing knnmatch are taking more time than the CPU version.

Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. :)