# How do I wrap the Cuda version of SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow using Cython?

Tags: opencv, cython, wrapper, opticalflow

I'm trying to wrap the Cuda version of the `SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow` OpenCV algorithm using Cython. So far I've based my code mostly on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828944/using-opencv-cuda-functions-from-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) with the modifications in its answer. I think I have to initialize an instance of the `SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow` class and then use the member function `calc` that the class inherits from `SparseOpticalFlow`.

Here's what I have so far:

**Corner_Tracker.pxd**

```
from libcpp cimport bool
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

# References PyObject to OpenCV object conversion code borrowed from OpenCV's own conversion file, cv2.cpp
cdef extern from 'pyopencv_converter.cpp':
    cdef void import_array()
    cdef PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Mat& m)
    cdef bool pyopencv_to(PyObject* o, Mat& m)

cdef extern from 'opencv2/imgproc.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef enum InterpolationFlags:
        INTER_NEAREST = 0 
    cdef enum ColorConversionCodes:
        COLOR_BGR2GRAY

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/core.hpp':
    cdef int CV_8UC1
    cdef int CV_32FC1

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef cppclass Size_[T]:
        Size_() except +
        Size_(T width, T height) except +
        T width
        T height
    ctypedef Size_[int] Size2i
    ctypedef Size2i Size
    cdef cppclass Scalar[T]:
        Scalar() except +
        Scalar(T v0) except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/core.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef cppclass Mat:
        Mat() except +
        void create(int, int, int) except +
        void* data
        int rows
        int cols
    cdef cppclass Algorithm:
        Algorithm() except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/cuda.hpp' namespace 'cv::cuda':
    cdef cppclass GpuMat:
        GpuMat() except +
        void upload(Mat arr) except +
        void download(Mat dst) const
    cdef cppclass Stream:
        Stream() except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp' namespace 'cv':
    cdef cppclass Ptr[T]:
        Ptr() except +
        Ptr(Ptr*) except +
        T& operator* () except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp' namespace 'cv::cuda':
    cdef cppclass SparseOpticalFlow:
        void calc(GpuMat prevImg, GpuMat nextImg, GpuMat prevPts, GpuMat nextPts, GpuMat status) except +

cdef extern from 'opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp' namespace 'cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow':
    cdef cppclass SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow(SparseOpticalFlow):
        @staticmethod
        Ptr[SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow] create(Size winSize, int maxLevel) except +
```

I suspect I'm not entering the `calc` argument types correctly, but I'm not sure what else to do.

**Corner_Tracker.pyx**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
cimport numpy as np
from cython.operator cimport dereference

def cudaCalcFlowWrapper(
        np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=2] prevImg,
        np.ndarray[np.uint8_t, ndim=2] nextImg,
        np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] prevPts):

    np.import_array()

    cdef Ptr[SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow] flow_tracker = SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow.create(Size(15,15), 2)  

    cdef Mat prevImgMat
    cdef GpuMat prevImgGpu
    pyopencv_to(<PyObject*> prevImg, prevImgMat)
    prevImgGpu.upload(prevImgMat)

    cdef Mat nextImgMat
    cdef GpuMat nextImgGpu
    pyopencv_to(<PyObject*> nextImg, nextImgMat)
    nextImgGpu.upload(nextImgMat)

    cdef Mat prevPtsMat = Mat()
    cdef GpuMat prevPtsGpu
    pyopencv_to(<PyObject*> prevPts, prevPtsMat)
    prevPtsGpu.upload(prevPtsMat)

    cdef Mat nextPtsMat
    cdef Mat statusMat
    cdef GpuMat nextPtsGpu
    cdef GpuMat statusGpu

    dereference(flow_tracker).calc(prevImgGpu, nextImgGpu, prevPtsGpu, nextPtsGpu, statusGpu)

    nextPtsGpu.download(nextPtsMat)
    statusGpu.download(statusMat)

    cdef np.ndarray nextPts = <np.ndarray> pyopencv_from(nextPtsMat)
    cdef np.ndarray status = <np.ndarray> pyopencv_from(statusMat)

    return nextPts, status
```

**setup.py**

```
import subprocess
import os
import numpy as np
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

# Determine current directory of this setup file to find our module
CUR_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Use pkg-config to determine library locations and include locations
opencv_libs_str = subprocess.check_output("pkg-config --libs opencv".split()).decode()
opencv_incs_str = subprocess.check_output("pkg-config --cflags opencv".split()).decode()

# Parse into usable format for Extension call
opencv_libs = [str(lib) for lib in opencv_libs_str.strip().split()]
opencv_incs = [str(inc) for inc in opencv_incs_str.strip().split()]

extensions = [ 
    Extension('Corner_Tracker',
              sources=[os.path.join(CUR_DIR, 'Corner_Tracker.pyx')],
              language='c++',
              include_dirs=[np.get_include()] + opencv_incs,
              extra_link_args=opencv_libs)
]

setup(
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
    name="Corner_Tracker",
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions)
)
```

When I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, I get this:

```
Compiling Corner_Tracker.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing Corner_Tracker.pyx
running build_ext
building 'Corner_Tracker' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/home/sccarey/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Corner_Tracker.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Corner_Tracker.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /home/sccarey/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1816:0,
                 from /home/sccarey/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                 from pyopencv_converter.cpp:2,
                 from Corner_Tracker.cpp:623:
/home/sccarey/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_14Corner_Tracker_cudaCalcFlowWrapper(PyObject*, PyArrayObject*, PyArrayObject*, PyArrayObject*)’:
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1843:67: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> struct cv::Ptr’
   cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow>  __pyx_v_flow_tracker;
                                                                   ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1843:67: note:   expected a type, got ‘cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow’
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1866:67: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T> struct cv::Ptr’
   cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow>  __pyx_t_3;
                                                                   ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1866:67: note:   expected a type, got ‘cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow’
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1868:3: error: ‘cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow’ names the constructor, not the type
   cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow __pyx_t_5;
   ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1868:60: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘__pyx_t_5’
   cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow __pyx_t_5;
                                                            ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1868:69: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
   cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow __pyx_t_5;
                                                                     ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1923:81: error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow>’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     __pyx_t_3 = cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::create(__pyx_t_2, 2);
                                                                                 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:1067:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:56,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
                 from pyopencv_converter.cpp:3,
                 from Corner_Tracker.cpp:623:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp:222:1: note: candidate is: cv::Ptr<T>::operator T*() const [with T = cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow] <near match>
 Ptr<T>::operator T* () const
 ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp:222:1: note:   no known conversion from ‘cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow*’ to ‘int’
Corner_Tracker.cpp:2022:5: error: ‘__pyx_t_5’ was not declared in this scope
     __pyx_t_5 = * __pyx_v_flow_tracker;
     ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp:2022:19: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)
     __pyx_t_5 = * __pyx_v_flow_tracker;
                   ^
Corner_Tracker.cpp:2028:5: error: ‘__pyx_t_5’ was not declared in this scope
     __pyx_t_5.calc(__pyx_v_prevImgGpu, __pyx_v_nextImgGpu, __pyx_v_prevPtsGpu, __pyx_v_nextPtsGpu, __pyx_v_statusGpu);
     ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've been playing around with it for a couple days, but I'm starting to think I'm just in too far over my head. 
Could someone please help me?

Edit: I fixed an unrelated error by replacing the memoryviews in the wrapper arguments with numpy arrays.

Edit: After applying the changes that @DavidW suggested, I'm getting this new error:

```
Corner_Tracker.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_14Corner_Tracker_cudaCalcFlowWrapper(PyObject*, PyArrayObject*, PyArrayObject*, PyArrayObject*)’:
Corner_Tracker.cpp:1868:36: error: cannot declare variable ‘__pyx_t_5’ to be of abstract type ‘cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow’
   cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow __pyx_t_5;
                                    ^
In file included from Corner_Tracker.cpp:628:0:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:160:18: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow’:
 class CV_EXPORTS SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow : public SparseOpticalFlow
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:99:18: note:         virtual void cv::cuda::SparseOpticalFlow::calc(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::cuda::Stream&)
     virtual void calc(InputArray prevImg, InputArray nextImg,
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:163:18: note:        virtual cv::Size cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::getWinSize() const
     virtual Size getWinSize() const = 0;
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:164:18: note:        virtual void cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::setWinSize(cv::Size)
     virtual void setWinSize(Size winSize) = 0;
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:166:17: note:        virtual int cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::getMaxLevel() const
     virtual int getMaxLevel() const = 0;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:167:18: note:        virtual void cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::setMaxLevel(int)
     virtual void setMaxLevel(int maxLevel) = 0;
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:169:17: note:        virtual int cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::getNumIters() const
     virtual int getNumIters() const = 0;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:170:18: note:        virtual void cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::setNumIters(int)
     virtual void setNumIters(int iters) = 0;
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:172:18: note:        virtual bool cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::getUseInitialFlow() const
     virtual bool getUseInitialFlow() const = 0;
                  ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp:173:18: note:        virtual void cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::setUseInitialFlow(bool)
     virtual void setUseInitialFlow(bool useInitialFlow) = 0;
                  ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error messages your main problem is the namespace declaration

```
cdef extern from 'opencv2/cudaoptflow.hpp' namespace 'cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow':
    cdef cppclass SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow(SparseOpticalFlow):
    # ...
```

The compiler output is reporting that

> error: ‘cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow’ names the constructor, not the type

Therefore you want to change the namespace for this class to `'cv::cuda'`.

---

This isn't the bug but if you declare `pyopencv_from/to` as

```
cdef object pyopencv_from(const Mat& m)
cdef bool pyopencv_to(object, Mat& m)
```

then you won't have to cast to `PyObject*`

---

The issue you're having with abstract variables comes from the line

```
dereference(flow_tracker).calc(prevImgGpu, nextImgGpu, prevPtsGpu, nextPtsGpu, statusGpu)
```

It's because it's trying to do (roughly):

```
SparsePyrLKOptical tmp_variable
try {
   tmp_variable = dereference(flow_tracker)
}
catch(...) {
   // handle errors
}
tmp_variable.calc(...)
```

Since `SparsePyrLKOptical` is abstract you can only create derived classes of it, but not actually the class directly.

If you remove `except +` from the line `T& operator* () except +` then Cython won't create the error checking code and so won't need the temporary. I suspect that this is right and that `operator*` can't actually throw an exception, but it has the potential to stop your program if it can.

Comment: Both of those suggestions seem to have worked! Thanks! Now I'm getting another error. I'll tack it onto the end of my post.

Comment: It compiled! There's no telling how long that might have taken me to find. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries. (In future, if you look look in the generated .cpp file it includes comments showing you the Cython code it matches. That should help you narrow down the problem, if not the solution)

Comment: Wiil do! Thanks!